# Missing system tray icons Ubuntu Gnome 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, system-tray

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and I am using the default Gnome. I updated and all of the system tray icons were missing.

Is this a bug? Can this be fixed? I cannot see any of the unread messages that I have in Skype / Slack etc. And there is no way to know about missed notifications.

Does someone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: It was an upgrade. But, I was using Unity for a long time and recently switched to gnome. For the first few days, system tray icons were visible. After an software update, its gone.

Comment: What is the output of the following command in Terminal: `apt policy gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`?

Answer (score 8):

You may also simply try to relaunch gnome shell and see if it works better:

```
(Alt+F2) gnome-shell --replace
```

Or the short and easy way

```
(Alt+F2) r (Enter)
```

Yes, just the letter "r".

Comment: this completely changed my desktop environment from gnome metacity to classic gnome :(

Answer (score 1):

I had it a few times that after an 18.04 update the icons were missing. In the past this fixed it:

```
sudo cpan -i Gtk2::AppIndicator
```

But this time this didn't worked. So removing Unity fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt purge unity-session unity
```

For the readers: only remove Unity when you are using the Gnome desktop. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Log in to Synaptic.
2. Type in search: `libappindicator`
3. Mark packages for installation:

   ```
   libappindicator0.1-cil
   libappindicator3-1
   libappindicator3-dev
   ```
4. Other `libappindicator` packages - if they are installed - mark for removal.

Comment: + for install : libappindicator1

Answer (score 0):

The icons having gone missing is explained here:
https://blogs.gnome.org/aday/2017/08/31/status-icons-and-gnome/

If you don't want to read all that, install this extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it, but having read that explanation on the blog the other "solutions" cannot work.