# Application System Tray - GNOME 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, system-tray, pidgin

I have the problem that system trays in Ubuntu 18.04.1 (using  GNOME) are not visible. I found a similar topic ([Missing system tray icons Ubuntu Gnome 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080632/missing-system-tray-icons-ubuntu-gnome-18-04)) but the command `sudo cpan -i Gtk2::AppIndicator` did not solve the problem. Maybe this can be of interest. During the removal operation of unity, I got the following error, which is related to the appIndicator:

```
Configuring O/OE/OESTERHOL/Gtk2-AppIndicator-0.15.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
pkg-config --cflags appindicator-0.1 gtk+-2.0 didn't succeed, make sure it is righly installed at Makefile.PL line 17.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
  OESTERHOL/Gtk2-AppIndicator-0.15.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
```

No system tray is visible and if I open skype or pidgin and close the application window, I cannot re-open the application in an easy way. Any link, support is appreciated. Thank you, Tobi

Answer (score 0):

According to the search on https://packages.ubuntu.com you need to install the following packages - [`libappindicator-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=appindicator-0.1.pc&searchon=contents) and [`libgtk2.0-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=gtk%2B-2.0.pc&searchon=contents):

```
sudo apt install libappindicator-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

and then retry with `sudo cpan -i Gtk2::AppIndicator`.

Comment: Hi @NOrbert, thank you for the hints. However, it does not work. Well, the removal is working now but I still do not have any system trays.

Comment: By installing this packages I have solved the warning message problem. You can use search on this site to get trayicons on modern GNOME (usually with the help of extensions).